# I used Abstract Class for interface. To which design pattern it can be associated?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I had used an abstract base class for interface and derived class for implementation. See the code below.. Can it be associated with any standard design patterns in c++?

```
Class people
{
    public:
       virtual void setname(string name)=0;
       virtual void SetAge(int Age)=0;
       //etc consists of only pure virtual functions like above
};

Class Students: public people
{
    void setname(string name) 
    {
        //implementation of the function
    }
    void SetAge(int Age) { //implementation }
}
```

And i had defined many classes as above and objects are created in constructor of a Buildclass as:

```
Buildclass::Buildclass()
{
    people *Obj = (people*) new Students();
    interface *obj1 = (interface*) new implementation();
}
```

And i had provided getinstance functions for above to be used in another layer

```
void BuildClass::getPeopleinstance()
{
   return Obj;
}
void BuildClass::getAnotherinstance()
{
   return Obj1;
}
```

Can the above code be associated to any design pattern? Please let me know? I am unable to find out.

Comment: To none, it is not even a valid C++.

Comment: Learn first programming, data structure, and algorithms. OOP should come when you know the basics. The classes should be designed around algorithms and data, not the other way round.

Comment: What are the mistakes in the above code? Please let me know.

Comment: @Rajesh: Try compiling it. Compiler will let you know.

Comment: What do u mean by  'not even a valid C++'. Can u point out exactly what u mean

Comment: Why do you care what design patterns your code might follow? As long as your code is good, it doesn't matter, and patterns are a guideline, not a checklist.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko I am using this code on a system and it was working perfectly fine. here just i had written a dummy example of it.

Comment: @Rajesh is new to SO, he needs rep give him a break. Just down-voting his question will not help him and he might not want to come back to SO.

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be using the Factory pattern, but it really doesn't matter. Focus on writing good code, not design patterns.